# .NET hiding buttons according to the SQL statement

Tags: asp.net

I need to hide these two buttons on the Homepage according to the value returned from the sql query.

```
<a onclick="editable(@item.Id2)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editpage" type="button" class="btn btn-light-warning font-weight-bold mr-2">
<i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>

<a onclick="deleted(@item.Id2)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" type="button" class="btn btn-light-danger font-weight-bold mr-2">
<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

Here's my SQL Query:

```
SELECT Action.ID2, [Personel List_T].NetworkName
FROM     [Personel List_T] INNER JOIN
                  [Departman List_T] ON [Personel List_T].Departman= [Departman List_T].[Departman List] INNER JOIN
                  Action ON [Departman List_T].ID = Action.RelatedDepartment
```

And the Query returns me a table like that:

```
ID2   | NetworkName | 
------+-------------+
6583  | MRTGD       | 
791   | SOMEUSER    |
```

At my index.cshtml i found network name and id2 with:

NetworkName:

```
@foreach (var item2 in User.Claims.Take(1)){
string ldapID = item2.Value; }
```

ID2:

```
@item.Id2
```

But according to the table returned from the sql query, if id2 and networkname are in the results, I have no idea how to activate/deactivate the buttons.

If ldapID=MRTGD and ID2=6583 I need to display buttons for this.Id2=6583 on DataTable, if they're not match i shouldnt be able to display buttons. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called SQLConnection on frontend. That will works perfectly.

```
 @{
                                                int result;
                                                string NetworkName1 = User.Claims.ElementAt(0).Value.ToString();
                                                string DptName = item.Department.ToString();
                                                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connection string gets here"))
                                                {
                                                    connection.Open();
                                                    string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) AS IsAuthorized FROM[Personel List_T] INNER JOIN [Departman List_T] ON [Personel List_T].Departman = @DptName WHERE ([Personel List_T].NetworkName = @NetworkName1)";
                                                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, connection))
                                                    {
                                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DptName", DptName);
                                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetworkName1", NetworkName1);
                                                   result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                                                }
                                                if (result > 0)
                                                {
                                                        <td style="width: 500px;">
                                                            <a onclick="somedata" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#somedata" type="button" class="btn btn-light-warning font-weight-bold mr-2"  style="width:45px;  margin-left: -10px; padding-left: -10px; !important;">
                                                                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                                            </a> 
                                                            <a onclick="deleted(@item.Id2)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" type="button" class="btn btn-light-danger font-weight-bold mr-2" style="width: 45px; position: relative; margin-right: -20px !important;">
                                                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                                            </a>


   
        <a onclick="alert('Unauthorized access.')" data-toggle="modal" id="buttonEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-light-dark font-weight-bold mr-2" style="height: 35.8px; width:45px;  margin-left: -10px; padding-left: -10px; !important;">
            <i class="fas fa-edit style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block !important;"></i></a><a onclick="alert('Unauthorized access')" data-toggle="modal" id="buttonRemove" type="button" class="btn btn-light-dark font-weight-bold mr-2" style="height: 35.8px; width: 45px; position: relative; margin-right: -20px !important;">
            <i class="fas fa-trash" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block !important;"></i>
        </a>
   
</td>
                                                    }
                                                    connection.Close();
                                                }
                                            }
```